# Getting Tests Run on Build with Azure DevOps REST APIs

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a REST API for getting the number of tests run/failed for a build?

I see there's one for getting [Code Coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/code%20coverage/get%20build%20code%20coverage?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) but unless I am missing something obvious I can't find an API for just getting the number of tests run for a build.

Looks like that all APIs available to get Test Results require a test *runid*, but I only have a *buildid*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use the [Runs - Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) API.  Pass the optional build id.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?minLastUpdatedDate={minLastUpdatedDate}&maxLastUpdatedDate={maxLastUpdatedDate}&buildIds={buildIds}&api-version=6.0
```

It's worth noting that you can customize the title of the run (with the build number included) by setting that on the task step of the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is endpoint dedicated for tests but you can get tests from logs

```bsh
$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$(System.AccessToken)")) }

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$(devopsAccount)/$(projectName)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/logs/$(logId)?api-version=5.1"

Write-Host $uri

# Invoke the REST call
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader

Write-Host $result

$lines = $result.Split([Environment]::NewLine)

$passed = 0;
$failed = 0;

foreach($line in $lines) {
    if ($line -match "Passed:.(\d+)") { 
      $passed = $matches[1]
    }

    if ($line -match "Failed:.(\d+)") { 
      $failed = $matches[1]
    }
}

echo $passed
echo $failed
```

You need to pass your build id and log id. To get log id please get all logs and go trough them and find the one with your task with tests.

In terms of buildId vs runId, they are the same. I mean buildId = runId. With newer syntax there were a change in nomenclature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Runs Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) Api as Matt mentioned. However i found the `buildId` query parameter didnot work probably. You may need to filter the api results by the buildId. See below example:

```
$connectionToken="Personal Access Token"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?minLastUpdatedDate=2020-10-20&maxLastUpdatedDate=2020-10-22&api-version=6.0"

$results= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $trurl -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get

$run = $results.value | Where-Object{$_.buildConfiguration.id -eq $buildId}

$runId = $run.id
```

You can also check out [Runs List Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). I found the buildId was always appended to the run title. You can filter api results by the run name. See below:

[image]

```
$connectionToken="Personal Access Token"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=6.0"

$results= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $trurl -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get

$run = $results.value | Where-Object{$_.name -match $buildId}

$runId = $run.id
```

Comment: Passing the buildid with the Runs - Query seems to be working, thanks for the alternative  suggestion of using the test run name, that would also work for me.